# Is it possible to exceed the int32 (into double) in DataColumn Expression?

Tags: c#

I've tried to make a calculator which will cover most stuff like power by and parentheses using System.Data DataTable + Columns and just load the equation in there as a string. Example: 10/2+32-5*3...  This to make it easier to code but I'm starting to think I should've done it another way.

When my friend and I wanted to test speed we exceeded the Int32 limit so now I wonder if it's possible to change it into the "double" limit?
The column needs to be able to exceed Int32 before the "table.Columns.Add(columns)" line, That's where it crashes

```
    static double Calculate(string formula)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(double);
        column.ColumnName = "Calculate";
        column.Expression = formula;

        table.Columns.Add(column); // Crash here and Exeption say Int32 limit exeeded

        table.Rows.Add(0);
        return Convert.ToDouble((table.Rows[0]["Calculate"]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to convert Int32 to Double like you did in the last line:

```
Convert.ToDouble((table.Rows[0]["Calculate"]));
```

But be careful of the variable type in which you are returning this value to. That is, the type of the variable must also be of type "Double" so that you do not get any error.

You can read more about it from this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayes1wa5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry, Wasn't being clear enough. 
Added more explination